# TypeScript doesn't raise error for incompatible promise returns

Tags: typescript

I am working on a generic API calling method that allows consumers to pass a request callback that should return a promise which resolves to a specified `<T>` payload (aka Action). It boils down to something like this:

```
interface MyAction { type: string, value: string; }

declare function call<T>(request: Promise<T>): void;

declare const request: Promise<{value: string}>;

// normal correct call
call<MyAction>(request.then(({ value }) => ({ type: "foo", value })));
```

The problem I'm having is that it seems the `then()` allows for a lot return values that aren't strictly compatible with `T`.

Here are some examples:

```
// bad: why no error on missing 'type'
call<MyAction>(request);

// good: error 'void' is not 'MyAction'
call<MyAction>(request.then(result => { }));

// good: error missing property 'type'
call<MyAction>(request.then(result => ({ fake: "foo" })));

// bad: why no error missing property 'value'
call<MyAction>(request.then(result => ({ type: "foo" })));

// bad: why no error for missing property 'type'
call<MyAction>(request.then(({ value }) => ({ value })));

// bad: why no error for unknown property 'fake'
call<MyAction>(request.then(({ value }) => ({ type: "foo", value, fake: "foo" })));

// bad: why no error for '{}' is not 'MyAction'
call<MyAction>(request.then(({ value }) => ({})));
```

My question is:

1. Why do these promises allow incompatible `T` return values? (Missing properties is the main concern.)
2. What, if anything, can I do to make the return values more strictly match the `T` passed to `call<T>()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // bad: why no error for unknown property 'fake'

This will always be okay as *more* info is allowed due to TypeScript's structural typing.

That said the following reduces your error conditions:

```
declare let both: Promise<{ type: string, value: string; }>;
declare let valueOnly: Promise<{ value: string }>;
declare let typeOnly: Promise<{ type: string }>;
declare let empty: Promise<{}>;

// Why no error?
both = valueOnly;
both = typeOnly;
both = empty;
```

> Why do these promises allow incompatible T return values? (Missing properties is the main concern.)

Because the type `T` is not used as a member in `Promise`.

> What, if anything, can I do to make the return values more strictly match the T passed to

You can change the `Promise` interface to use `T`

```
declare let both: Promise<{ type: string, value: string; }>;
declare let valueOnly: Promise<{ value: string }>;
declare let typeOnly: Promise<{ type: string }>;
declare let empty: Promise<{}>;

// Error!
both = valueOnly;
both = typeOnly;
both = empty;

interface Promise<T>{
  _ensureTypeSafety: T;
}
```

Also added here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/promise-safety.html

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize function compatibility rules were so different. Turning on promise `_ensureTypeSafety` works! However, now it unravel a deeper problem... `Promise<T>` represents what I want the promise to return, but in my example `request` is of type `Promise<{ value: string}>` and I want to return `T` in the success handler... if I enable `_ensureTypeSafety` my original "normal correct call" errors with `Property 'type' is missing in type '{ value: string; }'` -- how can I express this? Is it possibly at all with `Promise` to express that?

Comment: Looks like `promise` definitions are broken in TypeScript nightly :(

Comment: Its fixed in TypeScript 2017.03.08 

Comment: Any suggestion with my last question? Basically can I get my "normal correct call" to work without error, even though `request` is not of `Promise<T>` but returns `T` in a handler?